# Passing JSON object as parameter from View to Controller function?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Basically I've a panel called DummyPanel, Now on dummypanel initialize event I've called a controller function like as follows:

```
var me = component;
var fieldCollection = 
{
    "Order"      : 'ordNumber',
    "Ref": 'refNumber'
};

me.fireEvent('myControllerFunction','Param1', fieldCollection, 'Param3');
```

Now I want to get **fieldCollection** JSON object value within function **myControllerFunction**, to get value from **fieldCollection** I'm using following code:

```
 myControllerFunction(param1, collection, param3)
 {
    Ext.Msg.alert(collection.Order); 
 }
```

But it does not return anything. So please let me know how to resolve this problem!!

Any comment will appreciated!!

Comment: Arun, you would probably get a lot more activity on your questions if you would mark your correct answers when they are given to you.  People will start ignoring your questions if you do not acknowledge their help.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle of your example to highlight the problem? here is an example of jsfiddle for sencha-touch2 http://jsfiddle.net/lozenlin/yU6t6/

Comment: What do you mean "it does not return anything"?  You have no functions here which *should* return anything.  Do you mean that your event never fires?  Have you actually created the event on your panel? `this.addEvents('myControllerFunction')` for example.  You should probably name it something more sensible, but maybe you get the point. Either way, it's pretty straightforward to step through the Ext code during the event firing and see where you're losing track of your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what it means "But it does not return anything", but I'll try.

So, your "DummyPanel" view have a alias or itemId property. In yor controller (in init() function), you need "keep track" of your view. For example:

In your view:

```
me.fireEvent('myEventName','Param1', fieldCollection, 'Param3');
```

In your controller:

```
init:function(){
    var me = this;
    this.control({
        'panel[itemId=your-view-itemId]': { // call your function after event
            myEventName: me.myControllerFunction
        }
    });
    ...
},

...

myControllerFunction: function(...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a good guess.  It's not clear that the OP's listeners are set up correctly in the controller.

Answer (score -2):

Should it not be

`Ext.Msg.alert(collection["Order"])`?

Or if you want to keep Ext.Msg.alert the way it is fieldCollection should be defined this way

```
var fieldCollection = 
{
    Order : 'ordNumber',
    Ref : 'refNumber'
};
```

Comment: @Fawar JavaScript allows you both syntax. No real difference.  Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/89Xb8/

Comment: @Shaunak, not much of a pro in JS but I had some simillar issues in the project I am working on so I guess there was outside factor that made me think it worked that way.

Comment: This is still not working and I could not found what is the problem why it is not working.

Comment: could it due to the object never being initialized ( new()) ?